# Insert current DateTime manually in phpmyadmin using symfony

Tags: symfony, datetime, insert

So i send the data to the controller using ajax and i want to insert it in the comment table; everything works fine if i delete these two lines about inserting current datetime for the comment and setting my entity nullable
but how can i insert current datetime ;

Controller Code

```
 if($request->get('texte')==NULL)
    {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access 
        to this section.');
    }
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface)
    {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access 
        to this section.');
    }
    $comment = new Commentaire();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $veterinaire=$em->getRepository("MyAppUserBundle:User")->findOneById($request->get('cible'));
    $comment->setIdCible($veterinaire);
    $comment->setIdClient($user);
    $comment->setTexte($request->get('texte'));
   $literalTime    =   \DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i",date_default_timezone_get());

    $comment->setDate($literalTime);
    $em->persist($comment);
    $em->flush();
    return new  Response("");
}
```

My Entity :

> ```
>  /**
>   * @var \DateTime
>   *
>   * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
>   */
>    private $date;
> ```

I even tried to set my AppKernel __construct

```
public function __construct($environment, $debug)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set( 'Africa/Tunis' );
        parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
    }
```

Comment: Your call to `\DateTime::createFromFormat` is not correct. The timezone is to be passed as the 3rd parameter, not the 2nd. As @dlondero suggests, just use `new \DateTime()` or `new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Africa/Tunis'))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass a `DateTime` object to `setDate`:

```
$comment->setDate(new \DateTime());
```

or if you want to specify timezone:

```
$comment->setDate(new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Africa/Tunis')));
```

Of course you can extract creation of `DateTime` object from the `setDate` and have additional variable to pass.